# MonoTouch UITableViewController and TableFooterView

Tags: iphone, mono, uikit, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to develop a small iPhone application using MonoDevelop (v2.8) and MonoTouch (v4.2.2).

My home screen is represented by a UITableViewController which use a UITableView for presentation. I want to fill the UITableView.TableFooterView (which is a UIView object) with some other controls (two labels and two buttons).

To do this I have created a "subview" called SearchView, which is represented by a UIViewController and use a simple UIView for presentation. I assign this view as footer view of the tableview.

```
public partial class HomeScreen : UITableViewController
{    
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        SearchViewController searchViewController = new SearchViewController();
        this.TableView.TableFooterView = searchViewController.View;

    }
}
```

Is this right?

It is right to assume that usaually you create a view (UIView) and consume it by a UIViewController ?

Comment: You can run into issues with the above code (unrelated to your question) since `searchViewController` if a local variable and no reference to it will exists when `ViewDidLoad` return (the View will be referenced, not the controller). That makes it possible for the **GC** to collect `searchViewController` which can crash your application. The easiest way to avoid this is *promoting* your variable into a *field* (so a reference will exist once the method return).

Comment: Thanks poupuo. I'am already aware of this. I have put the declaration in the method just to make things understandable. I also know that this issue will be resolved in the near future by the monotouch team.

Any hint about my question?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
sBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,30)];
sBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:sBar];
```

you can add subviews like this ,sbar is the search bar,u can also add any controllers like button ,labels ,textview,textfield in it.

Comment: Yes I Know, but when the UITableViewController is created the this.TableView.TableFooterView property is null, so I can't do this.TableView.TableFooterView.AddSubView. I can't also add subview to the TableView (this.TableView.AddSubView) beacuse it renders wired things.

Answer (score 0):

In your UITableViewDataSource you can override public virtual UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, int sectionIndex)

```
    public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, int sectionIndex)
    {
        // Write a method to get the proper Section via the sectionIndex
        var section = GetSection(sectionIndex);
        if (section != null)
        {
            if (section.FooterView == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(section.FooterText))
            {
                // Create your FooterView here 
                section.FooterView = CreateFooterView(tableView, section.FooterText);
            }

            return section.FooterView;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As of iOS 5 you will also need to override

```
public virtual float GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, int sectionIndex)
```

and return the height of the FooterView